# Hide text in .bmp

Tags: c, bmp, steganography

I've made this function in C to put text inside a bmp image. I've tried to make it change only the least significant pixel of the red color. But when I open the edited image the blue is changed. The data comes from "stb_image.c" library.

```
int txt_bmp(char *tekst, int x, int y, unsigned char *data){
    int i, j, k, l = 0;
    unsigned char t,p = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(tekst); i++){    
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            t = 0x80;
            k = 1;
            p = tekst[i] & (t/k);
            p >>= (7-j);
            if (p == 0)
               data[l] &= p;
            data[l] |= p;
            k *= 2;
            l += 3;
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you assumed the wrong size for the header?

Comment: For bmp images the length of each line is multiple of 4 (filled with null bytes).

Comment: The return value from an image loader is an 'unsigned char *' which points to the pixel data. The pixel data consists of *y scanlines of *x pixels, with each pixel consisting of N interleaved 8-bit components; the first pixel pointed to is top-left-most in the image. There is no padding between image scanlines or between pixels. And I forced 3 components...

Answer (score 1):

When using the `BI_RGB` mode (a normal uncompressed DIB), the order of each triplet in a 24-bit DIB will be `blue, green, red` (i.e. the least significant byte is the blue component).

It's possible to switch the components around by using the `BI_BITFIELDS` mode and specifying a channel mask according to your own preference, but the `BI_BITFIELDS` mode isn't valid for 24-bit DIBs as far as I know.

So if you want to store something in the red component you should be using the most significant byte of each triplet.

Comment: // An output image with N components has the following components interleaved
// in this order in each pixel:
//
//     N=#comp     components
//       1           grey
//       2           grey, alpha
//       3           red, green, blue
//       4           red, green, blue, alpha

Comment: Ok, but that's not how they are stored internally in the original image. Does the code that saves the modified image assume the same reversed order (i.e. does it switch it back to blue,green,red)?

Comment: @magnums - like Michael says, just alter the value of the 3rd byte in each 3byte pixel, rather than the first..

Comment: I use stb_image.c and stb_image_write.h to import and export .bmp file. These libraries enable me to manipulate the picsel data like this:The image is a rectangle of pixels stored from left-to-right, top-to-bottom. Each pixel contains 'comp' channels of data stored interleaved with 8-bits per channel, in the following order: 1=Y, 2=YA, 3=RGB, 4=RGBA. And I always force the comp of the input image to be converted itno 3 (RGB) before inserting text. The comp of output is also 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this will create an uncompressed bitmap.
With a little modification, I've had it create and save to SD card a 256x256 rgb image on an arduino with 2kb of ram. (The pixel data alone is 192kb)

Currently, the code is commented so that it's a monochromatic image - the R channel only. Look at lines 155 to 157.

```
// 22nd September 2008
// 10:37pm
// Enhzflep


#include <stdio.h>              // for file I/O
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef WORD
 #define WORD unsigned short
#endif

#ifndef DWORD
    #define DWORD unsigned long
#endif

#ifndef BYTE
    #define BYTE unsigned char
#endif

#ifndef LONG
    #define LONG long
#endif

#define BI_RGB 0

#pragma pack(push,2)
typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER {
    WORD    bfType;
    DWORD   bfSize;
    WORD    bfReserved1;
    WORD    bfReserved2;
    DWORD   bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER,*LPBITMAPFILEHEADER,*PBITMAPFILEHEADER;
#pragma pack(pop)

typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER{
    DWORD   biSize;
    LONG    biWidth;
    LONG    biHeight;
    WORD    biPlanes;
    WORD    biBitCount;
    DWORD   biCompression;
    DWORD   biSizeImage;
    LONG    biXPelsPerMeter;
    LONG    biYPelsPerMeter;
    DWORD   biClrUsed;
    DWORD   biClrImportant;
} BITMAPINFOHEADER,*LPBITMAPINFOHEADER,*PBITMAPINFOHEADER;
typedef struct tagRGBQUAD {
    BYTE    rgbBlue;
    BYTE    rgbGreen;
    BYTE    rgbRed;
    BYTE    rgbReserved;
} RGBQUAD,*LPRGBQUAD;
typedef struct tagBITMAPINFO {
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmiHeader;
    RGBQUAD bmiColors[1];
} BITMAPINFO,*LPBITMAPINFO,*PBITMAPINFO;


bool writeBmp24(int width, int height, char *filename, char *data)
{
    BITMAPINFO myBmpInfo;
    unsigned long myInfoSize;
    BITMAPFILEHEADER myBmpFileHeader;
    FILE *outputFile;

    // different bmp file types use different headers
    // this is the one for 24 bit bitmaps
    myInfoSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    // magic signature
    myBmpFileHeader.bfType = 0x4D42; // 'BM'

    // reserved data - must be zero
    myBmpFileHeader.bfReserved1 = 0;
    myBmpFileHeader.bfReserved2 = 0;

    // offset into file of the pixel data
    myBmpFileHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + myInfoSize;

    // total file size
    myBmpFileHeader.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)
                         + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)
                         + myInfoSize
                         + width*height*3;

    // size in bytes of this header
    myBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(myBmpInfo.bmiHeader);

    // size in bytes of the pixel data
    myBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = width*height*3;

    // image dimensions
    myBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
    myBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = height;

    // pixels per meter (used to help select best image for output device)
    myBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 2835;
    myBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 2835;

    // only 1 pixel plane. Look up X-Mode (early 90s for more info on the concept of planes)
    myBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;

    // bits per pixel
    myBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;

    // compression type
    myBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    // only used for images with a pallette
    myBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
    myBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;


    if (!(outputFile = fopen(filename, "wb")))
        return false;

    if ( fwrite(&myBmpFileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outputFile) != 1)
        goto BmpError;

    if (fwrite(&myBmpInfo, myInfoSize, 1, outputFile) != 1)
        goto BmpError;

    if (fwrite(data, 3, width*height, outputFile) != width*height)
        goto BmpError;

    if (fclose(outputFile))
        return false;

    return true;

BmpError:
           fclose(outputFile);
           return false;
}

int main()
{
    int width = 128;
    int height = 128;

    char *pixelData;//[96*96*3];       //100x100 pixels * 24 bits/pixel
    char *dest;                                  // pointer to data
    int x, y;                                        // cur pixel
    char curVal;

    pixelData = (char*)calloc(3, width * height );
    dest = pixelData;                         // get locatio in mem of raw pixel data
    for (y=0; y<height; y++)           // for all rows of the image
        for (x=0; x<width; x++)       // loop through each pixel
        {
            curVal = x^y;
            dest[0] = 0;//curVal;       // b
            dest[1] = 0;//curVal;       // g
            dest[2] = curVal;           // r
            dest += 3;                            // point to next pixel;
        }

    writeBmp24(width, height, "enhzflep.bmp", pixelData);
    free(pixelData);
}
```